# How to draw a state map using R

Tags: r

I need help on how to use R to draw a map. I have created an excel csv file with latitude and longitude of counties at the boundaries of the state I want to draw. However, I don’t know the right codes in R to use and get the map drawn.
#R #Maps #howtodrawmapsinR #ggplot2 #Rmapcodes

Comment: I would suggest to start with one of the numerous tutorials on creating maps with ggplot2 such as e.g. https://remiller1450.github.io/s230s19/Intro_maps.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as:

```
library(maps)
map('county', 'iowa', fill = TRUE, col = palette())
```

If you like to use the data from your `.csv` file, then please have a look on `sf` and `sp` libraries and get familiar with creating simple geometries, like `SpatialPolygons`.

Comment: This worked like magic! Thanks a lot!